# Publishing large binaries fails some times

Tags: 2011, publishing

Publishing fails when handling large binaries.

I see that we can increase size limit of binary files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779054/error-uploading-large-binaries-into-sdl-tridion-multimedia-components).

Will this solve my issue.

Comment: Why not you try yourself and see if it works and in case you still see issue, post it back with more detail and your research

Comment: Your question is way too vague. Provide system details, version numbers and logs.

Comment: Looking at your comment within Harold's answer, it is unclear whether this question is regarding **saving** large binary files, or **publishing** large binary files.  @Patan - Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That link you refer to has nothing to do with publishing, but with uploading files into the CM
I assume you use the http(s) deploy method for publishing files. In that case, you should go to the web.config of your website where your httpupload.aspx file is hosted (that file is responsible for receiving the publish packages from your CM).

The web.config should contain these settings

```
<system.web>        
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096000" executionTimeout="300" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4096000000" />
     </requestFiltering>
  </security>
 <system.webServer>
```

I believe the system.webserver setting is required when you are on IIS7 or higher (also note this value is in bytes, while the system.web setting value is in kilobytes).

Note that, if you would be publishing extremely huge files, there might still be some transport issues or timeouts, depending on your connection settings. 
But, these settings will help you in most circumstances

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you tell me if it is applicable to IIS 6 also.

Comment: yes, the system.web setting (httpruntime...) is applicable for iis6. the system.webserver setting is applicable for iis 7

Comment: I implemented it. changed to 200MB. But I am getting transaction has aborted and unable to save the component. Uploading of component is success but saving fails.

Comment: could you please add some log files (maybe it's better to start a new question, it might be unrelated)

Comment: Its happening while saving large images only.

Comment: Error Code:
0x80040000 (-2147221504)
Call stack:
System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.CreateAbortingClone(InternalTransaction)
System.Transactions.DependentTransaction..ctor(IsolationLevel,InternalTransaction,Boolean)
System.Transactions.Transaction.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption)
System.Transactions.TransactionScope.SetCurrent(Transaction)
System.Transactions.TransactionScope.PushScope()
System.Transactions.TransactionScope..ctor(TransactionScopeOption,TransactionOptions,EnterpriseServicesInteropOption)

Comment: Don't forget the `MaxSize` property in the cd_deployer_conf.xml from the HttpUploader website!

Comment: could you please post the deployer.log and transport.log (from your deployer server) ?
Could you also tell me if you store your binaries in the filesystem or in a database