# Cannot save big(500MB) binary file as multimedia component

Tags: multimedia, binary

When creating multimedia component with a binary file(more than 500MB), following error occured.

> The transaction associated with the current connection has completed
>   but has not been disposed.  The transaction must be disposed before
>   the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.

So I modified configration on Content Manager Server as following.

- Increased value of "Seconds before a time out is generated when executing a query", in SDL Tridion Content Manger Configuration's Timeout Settings
- Increased following "transactionTimeout" value on Tridion.ContentManager.config.

> ```
>   <tridion.contentmanager>
>     <repository categoryEnumerationLimit="0" />
>     <license licenseFilePath="license.xml" />
>     <session transactionTimeout="600" />
>   </tridion.contentmanager>
> ```

- Add following "serviceTimeouts" element to "TcmServiceHost.exe.config".

> ```
> <behaviors>
>   <serviceBehaviors>
>     <behavior name="Tridion.ContentManager.ServiceHost.WindowsServiceHost.CoreServiceBehavior">
> <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:10:00" />
> ```

I read this article to do those configurations.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508729/sdl-tridion-times-out-when-publishing-multiple-items

By those configuration, the problem was solved temporarily.However, after creating few multimedia components, following error occurred, and creating or deleting multimedia component failed.

> A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure
>   "EDA_ITEMS_UPDATEBINARYCONTENT". Timeout expired.  The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not
>   responding.

I tried following SQL, but it doesn't solve the promblem(I got this SQL from this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565642/timeout-when-uploading-images)

```
SELECT 1 FROM BINARIES WHERE ID = -1 AND CONTENT IS NULL
```

How is it possible to create big size(500MB) multimedia component?

Comment: Please check, your config settings ({TridionDir}\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Web.config) are according to the answer: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3818/522 ?

Comment: I've already done the settings, otherwise uploading 500 MB file by "Load from Disk" is impossible. In my case, upload succeeds but saving by "Save and Close" button fails. I guess this is DB issue.

Comment: I have tried upto 250 MB and the upload / save is pretty consistent but we faced issues during publishing; when someone bulk publishes or publishes from a parent publication etc. (and I learnt never go against my personal feedback and SDL recommendations) . Do we need these large files to be author managed in Tridion? If it is just a one-time thing, I would consider moving the file directly to your presentation server, or atleast as an alternative till you move to a more robust solution. Tridion is a web content management system and is NOT built for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to put such a big file in CMS? should not do that.

Think about when you publish it. it will move from CMS to CD server ie. 500 MB file, it will throttle your publishing queue.

if you want to do that. check following link it may help

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/CME_concept_242A17EC385644C8A77F2C976576492C

Answer (score 1):

SDL Web is not a document management system. It is not best practice to store large media files in SDL Web. Doing so would cause issues during publishing of such assets, clogging your publishing queue and deteriorating the editor's experience.

Instead, it is recommended to use a media asset repository for such large files such as SDL Media Manager or a CDN, and simply reference the final URL of the asset into an SDL Web's multimedia component for instance. Or using ECL (External Content Library) such as SDL's connector for Media Manager which makes it easy for editors to insert external assets (coming from MediaManager) directly into their Tridion managed pages. MediaManager then serves the assets from its CDN, also ensuring the best performance for end users.

Learn more on [SDL Media Manager here](http://www.sdl.com/cxc/digital-experience/web-experience-management/digital-asset-management.html)

[ECL Connector for MediaManager Documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20Connector%20for%20Media%20Manager-v2&lang=en-US)