# Publishing big pdf files not working

Tags: 2013, publishing, deployer, binary

We can publish the pdf files of size below 2mb but can't publish over 2 mb files.
When we publish the pdf files of size over 2 mb, the publish queue immediately shows the 'Sucess' state, But when we checked on the file system, the file is not there.Can you please advise us what could be the problem?

Thanks,
Suneetha

Comment: Please check the deployer logs for any errors. Also have a look on your deployer and storage config files for file/package size related settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/3817/129

Answer (score 3):

try to increment the MaxSize parameter in your cd_deployer_conf.xml

also you can change the next file $Tridion_Home\Content Porter\ImportExportService\web.config

change the value of “maxAllowedContentLength” to “209752100”
(to allow files until 200mb)

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209752100" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 3):

Timeout does not seem to be the issue if you get an immediate success message. If there's a timeout, I would expect a failure at possibly the commit stage of publishing. When you publish the file, open the dropdown of the publishing window to check if items are actually being published. The multimedia component need to be added to a page (if embedded) or uses a dynamic CT to be publishable.